# Generating series

Tags: java, c#, .net, algorithm, permutation

I'm looking for an explanation on the following problem

Given an input - array of integers such as `1 2 3 4` I want to produce all of the possible "permutations" which look like this`0 0 0 1 , 0 0 0 2`, first one goes like this until `0 0 0 4` , next one looks like this `0 0 1 0` and then `0 0 1 1` .I hope you got my point.I have already constructed an iterative algorithm which produces the series but it uses too much memory for an input of size 10, the solution I'm looking for doesn't use recursion. Please note that there are `(n + 1)! (0,0,0,0 included)` possiblities.

The input is limited to integers and it is always the case that the count of values generated equals the count of the input values.

*EDIT*

Please note that there might be such a solution here in Stackoverflow but I can't really define a proper name for the problem that's why if anyone has any clue on how to actually name this problem,please do share!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate your series you basically do this:

- Start with an array containing only zeroes, of the correct length
- Iterate, and for each iteration do "basic math" like incrementation of the number, as though each element of the array is a single digit of a larger number.

  - Basically increment the last number by 1
  - If this ends up being higher than the max for that position, reset it to 0 and move on to the digit to the left
  - If it didn't end up being higher than the max, you got a new solution
  - When the move-on-to-the-digit-to-the-left operation falls off the left end of the array, you're done

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) solution that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    CountedPermutations(1, 2, 3)
        .Select(l => new { a = l[0], b = l[1], c = l[2] })
        .Dump();
}

public static IEnumerable<int[]> CountedPermutations(params int[] maxValues)
{
    int[] results = new int[maxValues.Length];

    yield return results; // the all-zeroes solution
    while (true)
    {
        // Increment to next solution
        if (CountedPermutationsMutate(results, maxValues))
        {
            // make a copy of the array and yield return it
            // we make copies so that if the outside code puts everything in a
            // collection, we don't just end up with N references to the same array
            // with the same values.
            yield return results.ToArray();
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}

public static bool CountedPermutationsMutate(int[] values, int[] maxValues)
{
    int index = values.Length - 1;
    bool gotSolution;

    while (true)
    {
        if (values[index] < maxValues[index])
        {
            // won't overflow this position, so we got a new solution
            values[index]++;
            gotSolution = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Overflow in this position, reset to 0
            // and move on to the next digit to the left
            values[index] = 0;
            index--;

            // If we fell off the left end of the array, we're done
            if (index < 0)
            {
                gotSolution = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return gotSolution;
}
```

This will output:

```
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 2 
0 0 3 
0 1 0 
0 1 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 3 
0 2 0 
0 2 1 
0 2 2 
0 2 3 
1 0 0 
1 0 1 
1 0 2 
1 0 3 
1 1 0 
1 1 1 
1 1 2 
1 1 3 
1 2 0 
1 2 1 
1 2 2 
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) to avoid storing of every generated value.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the algorithm which creates the permutations.It does require a dynamically created loop such that recursion can provide.I will use the yield return statement for sure tho.